# Error when try to parse json?

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to parse JSON, but it's not working. I want to get `id` from the JSON at the URL, but it shows me null value.

```
 var names = [String]()
 var SearchURL = "http://ios.khothe.vn/web/gamecards/authenticate/user/dungphiau/pass/829d81d46bad96825dc52a6e1675aab0"
 typealias jsonStandard = [String : AnyObject]

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     callAlamo(url: SearchURL)
 }

 func callAlamo(url : String)  {
     Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler:
     {
         responds in
         self.parseData(JsonData: responds.data!)
     })
 }

 func parseData(JsonData : Data)  {
     do{
         var readableJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as! jsonStandard
         let tracks = readableJson["id"] as? jsonStandard
         print(tracks)
     } catch{
           print(error)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Which value exactly is `nil`?

Comment: i want to parse value "id" in url and print it

Comment: Again, which line exactly is showing you a "null" value?

Comment: let tracks = readableJson["id"] as? jsonStandard

Comment: Still unclear. Is `readableJson` nil or is `tracks` nil? Use the debugger. See what each value is. Confirm that `readableJson` actually contains the key `"id"`.

Comment: readableJson is nil. please help me to parse  url: http://ios.khothe.vn/web/gamecards/authenticate/user/dungphiau/pass/829d81d46bad96825dc52a6e1675aab0 thanks Pro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for key `id` is `String` not `[String:AnyObject]` aka `jsonStandard`

```
let tracks = readableJson["id"] as? String
```

Consider that in Swift 3 the type of a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`

```
typealias jsonStandard = [String : Any]
```